# Making a program that intercepts network traffic in Windows

Tags: c, windows, networking, firewall

Sort of what I'm asking is "how to make a software firewall for Windows," but something not so complex. I'm surprised I can find so little when searching for this, only the occasional mention of hooks. So it'd be much appreciated if someone could point me in the right direction.

I expect to do this with C (though if there's another language you think would work better, I'm all ears). I want to make an application that watches network traffic, can extract the IP address (source for incoming, destination for outgoing), and can block said network activity.

This seems like something that would be much easier to do in the kernel, but I don't want to be mucking around in there, nor do I even have access to do that in Windows anyway. I'm not worried about efficiency, nor am I looking to make a personal firewall. This is just for an experiment regarding IP addresses.

Any pointers?

**Note: It's important that I be able to block network certain network activity too, not just monitor it**

Comment: You want to look at [libpcap and tcpdump](http://www.tcpdump.org/).

Comment: tcpdump and libpcap do not run on windows. I think you meant WinPcap and WinDump.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The DIY way would be going in kernel mode, using [filter-hook drivers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff546489%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (for Windows 2000-XP) or [WFP Callout Drivers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff571068%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).

If you want to let others do the dirty work in kernel-mode, the [WinPcap](http://www.winpcap.org/) driver/library sports lots of low-level network features, including the ones you need, that you can use from user-mode (notice that using WinPcap you can't drop packets).

Comment: I should have made this more clear in the original question, but dropping packets (what I assume I need to do to block network traffic) is an important requirement here. Several people suggested WinPcap, but it doesn't have that capability? In that case, I should look into those filter-hook drivers then.

Comment: @cost: no, it doesn't have such capability, as explained in its FAQ page.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like what you're looking for is a Winsock [Service Provider Interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms741418.aspx) (SPI) [Layered Service Provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb513664.aspx) (LSP). From what you've said, if you're dealing with Vista or newer, you probably want to implement an instance of the LSP_INSPECTOR class. For older versions of Windows, that class doesn't apply exactly, but the same general idea does. On Vista/7, you set the category (class) for your application with [`WSCSetApplicationCategory`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742253.aspx). To install your provider, you fill out a [`WSAPROTOCOL_INFO`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms741675.aspx) structure, then register it by calling [`WSCInstallProvider`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742252.aspx).

Comment: This looks like the best solution. Can it intercept data sent to a TCP socket in a program that is already compiled?

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for is a packet sniffer, it will intercept almost all communications over a network. If you want to use a library, check out [WinPCap](http://www.winpcap.org/), which was meant for exactly this purpose.

Also, if you think that you just want something pre-written and just want to modify it, check out [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/). Although, reading code is often more difficult than writing it.