# How to capture all internet traffic in node

Tags: node.js, socket.io, electron, tunnel

I am looking to make an application (with [*electron*](http://electron.atom.io/) preferably) that can route all internet traffic on a device (currently targeting Windows) and tunnel/stream it through a socket (maybe using [socket.io](http://socket.io/) or [socket.io-stream](https://github.com/nkzawa/socket.io-stream)). Essentially what would be happening is an *OpenVPN-like* thing only using web technology.

I am wondering if there is a way of sniffing out all internet bound traffic from any/all programs or windows itself and route it. Any help would greatly be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The answers in [Making a program that intercepts network traffic in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5682875/making-a-program-that-intercepts-network-traffic-in-windows) seem relevant, and there's a [Node module](https://github.com/mscdex/cap) you could try.

Comment: [Cap](https://github.com/mscdex/cap) seems like a a good place to start. Have you used it before?

Comment: @davejoem No I haven't.